# Random length For loop only generating low numbers

Tags: javascript, loops, random, for-loop

So I have a for loop that loops a random number of times:

```
for(var i = 0; i<Math.floor(Math.random()*100); i++){
  var num = i
}
```

which works, but seems to be biased on the low side. Just running it a few times 'num' never seems to return anything much above 20. Change our domain to Math.random()*1000 doesn't seem to return anything much above 40.

This was just a bit of messing about so doesn't require any practical work around, just curious about the explanation.

Here's a quick link to the working code to test out yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv45r/1/

Comment: this looks like an XY question... what are you trying to do that even requires a random-length iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, your random number that determines the number of loops is being evaluated on *every* iteration. Change the code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var loops = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        for(var i=0; i<loops; i++){
            var num = i
        }
        alert(num);
    })
})
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv45r/3/

Answer (score 4):

In your version in every loop a new random number is generated. This leads to a bias towards lower numbers. To solve this first create your number and then loop:

```
for(var i = 0, max=Math.floor(Math.random()*100); i<max; i++){
  var num = i
}
```

or

```
var max = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
for(var i = 0; i<max; i++){
  var num = i
}
```